# RepeatedHeaderTableDrawer does not show all rows in several pages

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm trying to draw a big table (that should be drawn in more than one page) using the library easytable.
I used the class RepeatedHeaderTableDrawer to repeat the table header in every new page. The header will be shown as expected. But the problem is that the rest of the table, which contains the data is not displayed correctly: *the shown table does not biginn from the beginnig of the table supposed to be shown*(some rows are missing), *the last row is also repeated* and *after ending all data-rows, more repeated rows are shown until the end of the last page*.
I know these are many problems in one, but may be one adaptation may resolve them all.

The method that creates the table is the following:

```
private static Table createCalculationTable() {

    final  Color ORANGE_DARK = new Color(245, 120, 60, 243);
    final  Color YELLOW_LIGHT = new Color(226, 212, 75, 255);
    final  Color ORANGE_LIGHT = new Color(234, 147, 90, 220);

    final Table.TableBuilder tableBuilder = Table.builder()
            .addColumnsOfWidth(100, 100, 100, 100, 100)            
            .fontSize(8)
            .font(HELVETICA)
            .borderColor(WHITE);

    // add the header row
    tableBuilder.addRow(Row.builder()
            .add(TextCell.builder().text("Name").horizontalAlignment(LEFT).borderWidth(1).build())
            .add(TextCell.builder().text("First Number").borderWidth(1).build())
            .add(TextCell.builder().text("Second Number").borderWidth(1).build())
            .add(TextCell.builder().text("Third Number").borderWidth(1).build())
            .add(TextCell.builder().text("TOTAL").borderWidth(1).build())
            .backgroundColor(ORANGE_DARK)
            .textColor(WHITE)
            .font(HELVETICA_BOLD)
            .fontSize(9)
            .horizontalAlignment(CENTER)
            .build());

    // add data rows
    double grandTotal = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < DATA.length; i++) {
        final Object[] dataRow = DATA[i];
        final double total = (double) dataRow[2] / 60 * (double) dataRow[3];
        grandTotal += total;

        tableBuilder.addRow(Row.builder()
                .add(TextCell.builder().text(String.valueOf(dataRow[0])).horizontalAlignment(LEFT).borderWidth(1).build())
                .add(TextCell.builder().text(String.valueOf(dataRow[1])).borderWidth(1).build())
                .add(TextCell.builder().text(String.valueOf(dataRow[2])).borderWidth(1).build())
                .add(TextCell.builder().text(dataRow[3] + " €").borderWidth(1).build())
                .add(TextCell.builder().text(total + " €").borderWidth(1).build())
                .backgroundColor(i % 2 == 0 ? YELLOW_LIGHT : ORANGE_LIGHT)
                .horizontalAlignment(RIGHT)
                .build());
    }

    // add the final row
    tableBuilder.addRow(Row.builder()
            .add(TextCell.builder().text("Total")
                    .colSpan(4)
                    .lineSpacing(1f)
                    .borderWidthTop(1)
                    .textColor(WHITE)
                    .backgroundColor(ORANGE_DARK)
                    .fontSize(9)
                    .horizontalAlignment(CENTER)
                    .font(HELVETICA_OBLIQUE)
                    .borderWidth(1)
                    .build())
            .add(TextCell.builder().text(grandTotal + " €").backgroundColor(ORANGE_DARK)
                    .font(HELVETICA_BOLD_OBLIQUE)
                    .verticalAlignment(TOP)
                    .borderWidth(1)
                    .build())
            .horizontalAlignment(RIGHT)
            .build());

    return tableBuilder.build();
}
```

The Data table is defined as following:

```
 private final static Object[][] DATA = new Object[][]{
        {"BEGINNNN", 10.0, 150.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_1", 10.0, 150.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_11",   10.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_111",    5.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_1111",  5.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_2",   10.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_22",    5.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_222",  5.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_2222",   10.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_3",    5.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_33",  5.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_333",   10.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_3333",    5.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_4",  5.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_44",   10.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_444",    5.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_4444",  5.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_5",   10.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_55",    5.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_555",  5.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_5555",   10.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_6",    5.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_66",  5.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_666",   10.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_6666",    5.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_66666",    5.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_7",  5.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_77",   10.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_777",    5.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_7777",  5.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_77777",  5.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_8",   10.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_88",    5.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_888",  5.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_8888",   10.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_88888",   10.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_9",    5.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_99",  5.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_999",   10.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_9999",    5.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_99999",  5.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_2",   10.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_3",    5.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_4",  5.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_2",   10.0, 200.0, 0.20},
        {"Location_3",    5.0, 200.0, 0.20}, 
        {"Location_4",  5.0, 200.0, 0.20},   
        {"ENDDDDDD ",  5.0, 200.0, 0.20}
    };
```

The following method calls the createCalculationTable method to insert the created table :

```
 public static void insertTable(String formPath, String formTargetPath) {

        try {
            PDDocument document = Loader.loadPDF(new File(formPath));
            final PDPage page = document.getPage(0);

            float startY = page.getMediaBox().getHeight() - PADDING;

            Table table = createCalculationTable();
            RepeatedHeaderTableDrawer.builder()           
                    .numberOfRowsToRepeat(1)
                    .page(page)
                    .table(table)                
                    .startX(PADDING )
                    .startY(startY )                             
                    .build()
                    .draw(() -> document, () -> page, PADDING);            
            document.save(formTargetPath);
            document.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ObjectNotFoundException("PDF file couldn't be created");
        }
    }
```

I checked when the data fits exactly one page, the whole table will be shown correctly. But when there is only one more row that don't fit in the first page, I get the different problems noted below. I'm nearly sure that .endY(value) for RepeatedHeaderTableDrawer.builder() may resolve the problem of repeating rows after the end of the data. That means when there is no data more, the table ends and it will no more show redundant rows until the end of the last page, such as it is the case currently. But I didn't get how can I set this value to "when there is no more raws", because the table is changeable and it doesn't have a fix size.
Any idea/help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: This sounds a bit like a bug in the library. I'd suggest opening a bug report: https://github.com/vandeseer/easytable/issues/new

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm not sure if it is a bug. Any way it is almost an old thread and I have already changed to the library boxable.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument of the draw() method takes a Supplier rather than just a page. The difference is that instead of allocating a new page, the library attempts to use the same page over and over.

This should work:

```
RepeatedHeaderTableDrawer.builder()           
                .numberOfRowsToRepeat(1)
                .page(page)
                .table(table)                
                .startX(PADDING )
                .startY(startY )                             
                .build()
                .draw(() -> document, () -> new PDPage(), PADDING);
```